# Combine two Add statements into one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to combine the two Add statements below into one statement?  Each adds an object to a list (accountTypeOptions)

```
accountTypeOptions.Add(new()
{
    Text = "Easy Access",
    Value = BankAccountType.EasyAccess.ToString()
});

accountTypeOptions.Add(new()
{
    Text = "Fixed Term",
    Value = BankAccountType.FixedTerm.ToString()
});
```

Comment: You could do `AddRange(new[] {new() {...}, new() {...}})` but that creates a temporary array that just gets thrown away.

Comment: Thanks, this is what a certain AI suggested but it produces a syntax error.  No a huge problem, just wondered if there was already a syntax available for this type of thing

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to do this, although if you use a collection initializer when instantiating the list, you can minimize the typing:

```
var accountTypeOptions = new List<AccountTypeOption>
{
    new()
    {
        Text = "Easy Access",
        Value = BankAccountType.EasyAccess.ToString()
    }),
    new()
    {
        Text = "Fixed Term",
        Value = BankAccountType.FixedTerm.ToString()
    }

};
```

Note that collection initializers are simply syntactic sugar for abstracting away multiple calls to `.Add()`. The following:

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
    "one", 
    "two"
};
```

compiles to:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");
```

---

That said, nothing prevents you from creating an extension method for this behavior:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this List<T> list, params T[] itemsToAdd)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsToAdd)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one", "two");
```

Note that using params does generate a backing array for the passed arguments which is less efficient, but if this isn't a hot path, it may be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra length with the extension example.  Am I correct in understanding that multiple items may only be combined into a single statement during the initialisation of the list?

Comment: @MusaffarPatel I updated my answer. It's syntactic sugar that the compiler provides that merely calls .Add multiple times behind the scenes. If you already have a collection, you can call .AddRange instead.

Comment: Collection initialization works with any class that implements `IEnumerable` (generic or not) and has one or more `Add` methods with a signature like `void Add(SomeType obj, [SomeTypeN objN]...)`